# Matlab math function is not iterating through an array

Tags: matlab

I have a function:

```
f=@(x) 1-(sin(x)/x);
```

and when I put in my array h with 12 items in the array (.1 .01 .001 ... .000000000001)
it comes out with just 1 number.

Any help on how to get my f to go through every item in my h would be helpful.

Here is a snipped image of everything I have

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Element-Wise Operations

This is a case where scalar/elemental operations occur. Using . will apply the function to all the elements

• "./" -> Division over all elements in array

• ".*" -> Multiplication over all elements in array

```
f = @(x) 1-(sin(x)./x);

Results = f(h);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you very much.... figured it was something simple I had overlooked